# Shutdown a domain client automatically through server

Tags: shutdown, vbscript, windows-server

so this one here is from a noob, please bear with me.

So I want to shut down the computers connected to my domain automatically everyday at 4:15 pm. Now I have been snooping around and have found out that we can do this through task scheduler using shutdown.exe

So far so good, but what if I want to display a cute message that warns the user that's currently logged into that client, that the system is shutting down in like 5 minutes. Based on what my snooping tells me, this is possible using VB. 
Problem is, I have literally no idea what that is. Could someone be kind enough to explain what it is all about?

Thanks if you made it this far tho :)

Comment: [lmgtfy: "What is VB?"](http://letmegooglethat.com/?q=What+is+VB%3F)

Answer (score 1):

VB is short for (Visual Basic Script), below is the code to run the VB to perform your task. [Code reference](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/0f24a791-3b6f-43f4-b2ff-1b92a1471d22)

Step 1) Download a text editor to put your code in to [Click here](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/repository/7.x/7.7.1/npp.7.7.1.Installer.exe)

Step 2) Copy and Paste the code below into the text editor

Step 3) Click **File** then **Save As** - *don't click save yet*

Step 4) Make sure you have *Save as type* Set to *All types*

Step 5) Call the **File name** **remoteShutdown.vbs** - *don't forget the .vbs!*

Step 6) Click **File** then **Open containing folder** then click **Explorer**

Step 7) Double click your script that you just created!

Step 8) When the script ask's you **"Perform action on what computer?"** enter the computers name on the network you wish to control.

Step 9) Answer 2 for the next question

Step 10) Find a website where you can learn how to code in VBScript [Start here](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=aq1XXaixAYnt9QOxh4rABw&q=learn%20vbscript)

**Below is the code to go in notepad ++**

```
strComputer=InputBox("Perform action on what computer?","Enter Computer 
Name",strComputer)  

'if no computername is specified (blank), then quit  
If strComputer = "" Then WScript.Quit  

strComputer = UCase(strComputer)  


RestartMode = InputBox("I would like to perform the following action on " & 
strComputer & ":" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf _  
 & "0 - Restart " & strComputer & vbcrlf _  
 & "1 - Logoff " & strComputer & vbcrlf _  
 & "2 - Shutdown " & strComputer & vbcrlf _  
 & "3 - Do nothing " & vbcrlf _  
 & vbcrlf,"Restart action",RestartMode)  

If RestartMode = "" Then  
   wscript.quit  
ElseIf RestartMode < 0 or Restartmode > 3 Then  
   wscript.echo "You must select a valid option between 0 and 3.  Script will now 
exit."  
   wscript.quit  
End If  

'You could also remove the above lines and declare your variables like this:  
' strComputer = "computername"  
' RestartMode = 1  
'0 = restart, 1 = logoff, 2 = shutdown, 3 = do nothing  
'also, with a little work, you could easily make command-line arguments for this  

Call RestartAction  

Sub RestartAction  
   Dim OpSysSet, OpSys  

   Set OpSysSet = GetObject("winmgmts:{(Shutdown)}//"_  
    & strComputer & "/root/cimv2").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_OperatingSystem"_  
    & " where Primary=true")  

   'set PC to reboot  
   If RestartMode = 0 Then  

      For each OpSys in OpSysSet  
         opSys.Reboot()  
      Next  

   'set PC to logoff  
   ElseIf RestartMode = 1 Then  

      Const EWX_LOGOFF = 0  
      For each OpSys in OpSysSet  
          opSys.win32shutdown EWX_LOGOFF  
      Next  

   'set PC to shutdown  
   ElseIf RestartMode = 2 Then  

      For each OpSys in OpSysSet  
         opSys.Shutdown()  
      Next  

   'set PC to do nothing  
   ElseIf RestartMode = 3 Then  


   End If  
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay so far great, but what if I want to run this as a script for a computer lab? I want them all to power off by 4:15(for example). Would I be creating a task in task scheduler through GPO?

Comment: Hello, I am a coder only. I would make a txt file with a list of computer names in it. I would modify the code above to run to each computer that's in the txt file.